# $x \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow x$ has periodic expansion in every real base q>1

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I've been trying for a while to show the proposition in the title of this post, but I find difficulties in the last step of the proof.
I kindly ask an advice on how to go further.
Meanwhile I show where I arrived.

I will use two partial results of which I omit the proof in order to make reading easier:

Lemma 1: $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $m\geq n$, $\exists ! q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \exists ! r \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ that verify $m=qn+r,r<n  $.
Lemma 2: given $q \in \mathbb{R}$, $q>1$, then $\forall x \in (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\exists ! k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $xq^{k-1}<1\leq xq^{k}$.

Now the proof:

I will consider the case $x=\frac{m}{n}<1$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ because after proved this, the other cases are trivial.

$ x=\frac{m}{n}<1\underbrace{\Rightarrow }_{\text{Lemma 2}}x=q^{-k_1}\underbrace{\frac{mq^{k_1}}{n}}_{\geq 1}\underbrace{=}_{\text{Lemma 1}} q^{-k_1}\left ( q_1+\underbrace{\frac{r_1}{n}}_{<1} \right ) \underbrace{=}_{\text{Lemma 2}} $
$=q^{-k_1}q_1+q^{-(k_1+k_2)}\underbrace{\frac{q^{k_2}r_1}{n}}_{\geq 1}\underbrace{=}_{\text{Lemma 1}}q^{-k_1}q_1+q^{-(k_1+k_2)}\left ( q_2+\underbrace{\frac{r_2}{n}}_{<1} \right ) \underbrace{=}_{\text{Lemma 2}}...= $
$ =\sum_{i=1}^{N}q_iq^{-(k_1+...+k_i)}+\frac{r_N}{n}q^{-(k_1+...+k_N)} =...$

with $q_1,... \in \mathbb{N}$, $r_1,... \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ and $k_1,... \in \mathbb{N}$.

Two cases may arise: $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} : r_N=0$, and then the sequence of digits $ \{q_k\} $ obtained has the form $q_1,q_2,...,q_{N-1},0,...,0,...$, or $\forall N \in \mathbb{N} \ r_N \ne 0 \Rightarrow$ since $0 \leq r_N < n$ then $\exists i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$r_i=r_{i-j}\Rightarrow k_i=k_{i-j}\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
q_{i+1}=q_{i-j+1}\\ 
r_{i+1}=r_{i-j+1}
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow k_{i+1}=k_{i-j+1} \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
q_{i+2}=q_{i-j+2}\\ 
r_{i+2}=r_{i-j+2}
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow ...\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
q_{i+(j-1)}=q_{i-1}\\ 
r_{i+(j-1)}=r_{i-1}
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow k_{i+(j-1)}=k_{i-1}\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
q_{i+j}=q_{i}\\ 
r_{i+j}=r_{i}=r_{i-j}
\end{matrix}\right. $

in other words, quotients and remains are repeated in groups of $i-j$ digits $\Rightarrow$ the sequence $\{q_k\}$ is periodic from a suitable index onwards.

Also note that in both cases the exponents $k_i$ are chosen such that (Lemma 2):

$ \frac{r_{i-1}q^{k_i-1}}{n}<1\leq \frac{r_{i-1}q^{k_i}}{n}=q_i+\frac{r_i}{n} $

from which $q_i<q$.

It remains to show that the sequence of digits $\{q_k\}$ so constructed is effectively the q-ary expansion of $x$.
The only case in which it is not, occurs when the expression of $x$ consists of an unlimited number of digits (second case) and also takes the form:

$ x=\sum_{i=1}^{M}q_iq^{-(k_1+...+k_i)}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left \lceil q-1 \right \rceil q^{-(k_1+...+k_M+i)} $

for a suitable $M \in \mathbb{N}$ (the square brackets in the expression indicate the upper integer part).

To conclude the proof I have to show that these particular numbers have periodic expansion in base $q$.
Here I am stuck because the only thing I can get is that these numbers are:

$ x=\sum_{i=1}^{M}q_iq^{-(k_1+...+k_i)}+\frac{\left \lceil q-1 \right \rceil}{q-1}q^{-(k_1+...+k_i)+1} $

and since $\left \lceil q-1 \right \rceil=(q-1)+(1-\{q\}) $ (braces = fractional part), I would have finished if I could state that $\frac{1-\{q \} }{q-1} $ has a periodic expansion in base $q$, but I can't  :(

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two minor criticisms and a question: the title of an MSE question is intended to be a brief description of the question. Please make the main text of the question self-contained. Also $\exists!q\exists!r\phi(x, r)$ is not logically equivalent to the statement "there exists a unique pair $(q, r)$ such that $\phi(q, r)$ holds", so if you must use fragments of logical notation in your narrative, you need to take a little care that you have said what you meant. Finally, is $q$ intended to be a positive integer or an arbitrary real number?

Comment: Yes, "there exists a unique pair such that...".
Then, q a real number greater than 1.

Comment: @RobArthan sorry for my logical notation. Now you make me curious about this: can you explain me the difference between "$\exists !q \wedge \exists !r$ such that..." and "there exists a unique pair $(q,r)$ such that...", please?
Thank you.

Comment: "There exists a unique $q \in \{0, 1\}$ such that there exists a unique $r\in \{0, 1\}$ such that $qr = 0$" is true - $q$ has to be $1$ so that $qr = 0$ forces $r=0$. "There is a unique pair $(q, r) \in \{0, 1\} \times \{0, 1\}$ such that $qr = 0$" is false - any pair other than $(1, 1)$ will do.

Comment: What restriction do you impose on the digits when the base $q$ is not an integer? E.g., when $q = 3/2$?

Comment: Thank you for the logical example, very useful.
Digits must be natural numbers (or zero) and less than q. In your example, if q=3/2 then digits can be only 0 or 1.

Comment: I am skeptical of the claim that, for example, $\frac12$ has a periodic expansion in base $\pi$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is an exercise from Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I.

Comment: @Mickin Looking at that exercise (Exercise 10 after section 2.2?) it's unclear to me that it is even intended to cover the case where $q$ is not an integer, much less the case where $q$ is irrational.

Comment: Sec. 3.1.5, Exercise 1.
I don't know if he means q natural, but anyway it's now interesting to know if the claim if true.

Comment: @Mickin Apart from everything else, apparently we've discovered that Zorich included the same exercise twice in two different parts of the textbook :)

Comment: Yes, it's true :)

Comment: There is some very useful information relating to this question in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation.

Answer (score 2):

If $q$ is transcendental, then no rational number will have a periodic $q$-ary expansion, unless it is an integer less than $q$.

Write a generic case of such an expansion, assuming $0<x<1$, as
$$
   x = 0.a_1a_2\dots a_k \overline{b_1b_2\dots b_\ell}.
$$
Then we have
$$
   x = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{a_i}{q^i} + \sum_{j=1}^\ell b_j \left(\frac1{q^{k+j}} + \frac1{q^{k+\ell+j}} + \dots\right) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{a_i}{q^i} + \sum_{j=1}^\ell \frac{b_j}{q^{k+j}}\left(\frac{q^\ell}{q^{\ell}-1}\right)
$$
and by multiplying through with $q^k(q^{\ell}-1)$ we obtain a nontrivial polynomial with integer coefficients satisfied by $q$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $q = \sqrt{x}$
then
$x = q^2$
so the representation
of $x$ in base $q$
is
$100.$

Comment: That's arguably periodic: it's $100.00000\dots$. (Assuming you were trying to give a counterexample, this isn't it.)